# How to pass input variables from php to matlab function

Tags: php, matlab

How can I pass the input variables from php into matlab function?
this is my code
in html part

```
    <form action="" method="post" style="margin-top:60px">
        Enter a Brangay ID <input type="text" name="input1"><br />
        Enter a Month Number <input type="text" name="input2"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"  /><br />
    </form>
```

in php part

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// form submitted, now we can look at the data that came through
// the value inside the brackets comes from the name attribute of the input field. (just like submit above)
$in1 = $_POST['input1'];
  $in2 = $_POST['input2'];
$inputDir  = "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin";
$command = "matlab -sd ".$inputDir." -r saladsalad('".$in1."','".$in2."')";
exec($command);
```

Comment: ps: the code doesn't trigger matlab

Comment: What output are you getting at the moment?

Comment: i want to pass the input variable from php so i can use the variables in matlab for test data prediction

Comment: This is very possible to do. Are you getting any errors at the moment? Is saladsalad() defined in your matlab home directory.

Comment: ahhm no errors at all sir and yes i defined it in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin